# Selenium get next tr given condition holds for previous tr

Tags: python, html, selenium, html-table

**Set-up**

I'm trying to scrape infoboxes on French regions on Wikipedia.

To be specific, I need to obtain the population of each region. For each region, its population is stated in the infobox on each wiki page, e.g. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayotte.

---

**HTML**

For the example page, the part of the infobox html I'm interested looks as follows,

```
<tr class="mergedtoprow">
   <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center;text-align:left">Area
       <div style="font-weight:normal;display:inline;"></div></th></tr>
<tr class="mergedrow">
   <th scope="row">&nbsp;•&nbsp;Total</th> 
       <td>374&nbsp;km<sup>2</sup> (144&nbsp;sq&nbsp;mi)</td></tr>
<tr class="mergedtoprow">
   <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center;text- align:left">
       Population 
       <div style="font-weight:normal;display:inline;">
            (2017)
            <sup id="cite_ref-census_1-0" class="reference">
                 <a href="#cite_note-census-1">[1]</a>
            </sup>
       </div>
   </th>
</tr>
<tr class="mergedrow">
   <th scope="row">&nbsp;•&nbsp;Total</th>
   <td>256,518</td>
</tr>
```

I need to get the population number 256,518.

---

**Code**

My plan is to select the `tr` containing the `'Population'` string and then tell selenium to select the `tr` after it.

The following code successfully selects the `tr` containing the `'Population'` string,

```
info_box = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.infobox').find_element_by_xpath('tbody')

for row in info_box.find_elements_by_xpath('./tr'):

    if 'Population' in row.text:

        print(row)
```

Now! How do I tell Selenium to select the `tr` after the selected `tr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to iterate over all rows. You just need to select required row

Try this code line to get required output:

```
population = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr[contains(th, "Population")]/following-sibling::tr/td').text
print(population)
#  256,518
```

Answer (score 2):

i think this should be good enough

```
info_box = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.infobox').find_element_by_xpath('tbody')
tr_data = info_box.find_elements_by_xpath('./tr')
for row in range(0, len(tr_data)):

    if 'Population' in tr_data[row].text:

        print(tr_data[row + 1].text) 
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

To extract the population you can simply identify the `<th>` with text as **Population** and identify the next `<tr>` node which have a descendent `<td>` containing the population **256,518** and you can use the following solution:

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//th[contains(., 'Population')]//following::tr[1]//td").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```